# A question on Normal Subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Let $K$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$ such that [$G :K$ ]$=m$ , if $n$ is a positive integer such that

gcd $(m,n)= 1$ then how to show that {$g\in G| o(g)=n$}$⊆K$ ?

Comment: Consider image of subgroup generated by this set by projection $G\to G/K$.

Comment: Only with extreme rarity are there reasons for a question to be written using abbreviations like «+ve».

Answer (score 1):

If $\gcd(m,n) = 1$ then exist $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $$am +bn = 1$$ Thus for all $g \in $ $\lbrace\in G| o(g)=n\rbrace$ we have $$g = g^1 = g^{am +bn} = g^{am}$$ Note that in $G/K$ every element has an order dividing $m$ and so $$gK = g^{am}K = (g^a)^m K = K$$ This means that such a $g$ is in $K$ , i.e. $$\lbrace g \in G| o(g)=n\rbrace \subset K$$